# JavaScript get drop-down values

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this two drop-down menus

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Year
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Year" id="Year" onchange="setAno()">
    <li><a href="#" id="Year" data-value="2016">2016</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Year" data-value="2017">2017</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Year" data-value="2018">2018</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Year" data-value="2019">2019</a></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Month
<span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="Month">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="01">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="02">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="03">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="04">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="05">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="06">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="07">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="08">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="09">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="10">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="11">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="12">12</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have a JavaScript function that need to use the data-values of the selected item but a can´t find a way to do that, if you can help me a really appreciate

Comment: Please post a snippet of your JavaScript function. It'll be helpful to analyse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not show drop-down menus, it shows bulleted lists with an `onchange` event handler. The only reason they look like drop-downs to you is because of the CSS styling that is being applied to them.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Year" id="Year" onchange="setAno()">
```

Lists don't support a `change` event. So, that's why your `setAno()` function is not being called. You'll need to either capture the `click` event from your list items or the links within them or actually use drop-down menus:

```
 <select class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Year" id="Year" onchange="setAno()">
    <option>some choice</option>
    <option>some choice</option>
    <option>some choice</option>
 </select>
```

Here's an example that keeps your lists, but captures the `click` event, rather than the `change` event (which never fires on lists):

```js
var theMonthLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#Month > li > a");
for(var i = 0; i < theMonthLinks.length; ++i){
    theMonthLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       console.log(this.getAttribute("data-value"));
    })
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="Month">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="01">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="02">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="03">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="04">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="05">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="06">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="07">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="08">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="09">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="10">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="11">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="12">12</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You forgot about CSS.

Comment: @AdamAzad How did I forget about CSS?

Comment: CSS can make that list appear as an select, yet it requires relatively extensive JavaScript to make it functional. One advantage of using this is styling options.

Comment: @AdamAzad Apparently you didn't read my answer. I said exactly that: *"The only reason they look like drop-downs to you is because of the CSS styling that is being applied to them."* However, it wouldn't take "extensive" code changes to make this work as my post describes.

Comment: @AdamAzad See my updated answer with a working sample. 6 lines of code is hardly "extensive".

Answer (score 0):

If you select your dropdowns via the standard document.getElementById, you should be able to get data attributes in pure Javascript via the dataset property of the element.